# Is the default value of textAppearance in android:theme="@style/AppTheme" textAppearanceSmall?

Tags: android

When I create a new android project,the default Theme is android:Theme.Light, I find the font size of TextView control is small,
does it mean the default value of textAppearance in android:theme="@style/AppTheme" is textAppearanceSmall? Thanks!

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
</style>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can find the styles used for all the Android widgets on the default styles.xml file. You can have a look to this file for example here: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml

Or directly into your SDK folder, for example on my computer it is available here: `D:\Dev\android-sdk\platforms\android-17\data\res\values\styles.xml`

You will find in this file the definition of the style for the `TextView`:

```
<style name="Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall</item>
    <item name="android:textSelectHandleLeft">?android:attr/textSelectHandleLeft</item>
    <item name="android:textSelectHandleRight">?android:attr/textSelectHandleRight</item>
    <item name="android:textSelectHandle">?android:attr/textSelectHandle</item>
    <item name="android:textEditPasteWindowLayout">?android:attr/textEditPasteWindowLayout</item>
    <item name="android:textEditNoPasteWindowLayout">?android:attr/textEditNoPasteWindowLayout</item>
    <item name="android:textEditSidePasteWindowLayout">?android:attr/textEditSidePasteWindowLayout</item>
    <item name="android:textEditSideNoPasteWindowLayout">?android:attr/textEditSideNoPasteWindowLayout</item>
    <item name="android:textEditSuggestionItemLayout">?android:attr/textEditSuggestionItemLayout</item>
    <item name="android:textCursorDrawable">?android:attr/textCursorDrawable</item>
</style>
```

You can see that indeed in this file the text size is defined with `textAppearanceSmall` by default.

Answer (score 8):

The `TextView` doesn't take the default `textAppearance`, it is set to be explicitly to use `textAppearanceSmall` by default.

`Themes.xml` contains the following line which defines default style for the `TextView`:

```
<item name="textViewStyle">@android:style/Widget.TextView</item>
```

The referenced style contains the following line:

```
<item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall</item>
```

This is why `TextView` defaults to small text size.