# TextAppearance not being applied on some API versions

Tags: android, themes, android-styles

I have a view I have created in XML. The view is then shown on one of two fragments. Either as the pause menu, replacing the board in my game activity, or a score summary at the end of a round on a DialogFragment.

Each TextView on my summary sets its textAppearance using an attribute declared in the theme for the view. This works without problem on my Sony Xperia Z3 Compact, running API 22. However, the text appearance doesn't seem to be applied at all on my wifes phone. Her's is a Z3 Compact running API 19. I also have a tablet running API 17 with the same problem.

On each of the devices with the problem, all the text is displayed with a very small text size. It also ignores the textColor set by the style.

The XML for each component looks like a variation on this:

```
<TableRow android:id="@+id/view_score_summary_group_overall_time">
    <TextView
        android:text="@string/time"
        android:textAppearance="?scoreSummaryTextAppearanceHeading"
        />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/view_score_summary_game_time"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:textAppearance="?scoreSummaryTextAppearanceData"
        />
</TableRow>
```

The attribute is then defined in my theme like this:

```
<style name="ScoreSummary.Light">
    <item name="scoreSummaryTextAppearanceHeading">@style/ScoreSummary.Light.TextAppearance.Heading</item>
    <item name="scoreSummaryTextAppearanceTitle">@style/ScoreSummary.Light.TextAppearance.Title</item>
    <item name="scoreSummaryTextAppearanceData">@style/ScoreSummary.Light.TextAppearance.Data</item>
</style>
```

The styles are then defined like this:

```
<style name="ScoreSummary">
</style>
<style name="ScoreSummary.Light">
</style>
<style name="ScoreSummary.Light.TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_score_summary_light</item>
</style>
<style name="ScoreSummary.Light.TextAppearance.Title">
    <item name="android:textSize">24sp</item>
</style>
<style name="ScoreSummary.Light.TextAppearance.Heading">
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">start</item>
</style>
<style name="ScoreSummary.Light.TextAppearance.Data">
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">end</item>
</style>
```

I then set the theme on the view (on my game activity) like this:

```
<com.abc.def.ScoreSummaryView android:id="@+id/fragment_game_score_summary"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:theme="@style/ScoreSummary.Light"
    />
```

So far I have tried a number of things:

1. Setting the attributes individually on the TextView.

   ```
   android:textSize="150sp"
   ```

   This worked. But if you have to set that on every component, why bother with styles at all.
2. Setting textAppearanceSmall instead of textAppearance. Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16956562/5139606). This just made all the text slightly larger, but still didn't apply my style.
3. Setting style instead of textAppearance. This had the same result as setting textAppearanceSmall.
4. Making my style declarations extend "android:attr/textAppearance". Didn't change anything, and I'm not sure why it would but I was desperate.

I've been looking at this for ages now, and I've tried googling a whole load of things but just can't get anywhere.

This is it looking wrong. On my tablet - though it looks similar on my wifes phone.

[image: This is it looking wrong. On my tablet - though it looks similar on my wifes phone]
This is how it's supposed to look. On my phone.

[image: This is how it's supposed to look. On my phone.]